# Postgres stream WAL segment removed

Tags: postgresql, write-ahead-logging

We have a master server and replication server running Postgres 9.3.6

Streaming was going slow due to a secondary failover router. It was running behind but still working.

I got a communication error and now I am getting the

```
ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000003150000001E has already been removed
```

However looking at the master server that file (and many before it) is still in the WAL directory.

I restarted the replication server and I do get the message

```
redo starts at 315/1A9CB5A0
[4018 - 2015-09-28 20:57:32 GMT]LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 315/1ED5E910
[4018 - 2015-09-28 20:57:32 GMT]LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 313/C0D60000 in log segment 00000001000003150000001E, offset 14024704
```

Is there any way to restart the streaming or will I have to pull down and do another basebackup?

Comment: Are there messages after the "unexpected pageaddr" line?

Comment: "the WAL directory". Do you mean `pg_xlog`? Or an archive directory?

Comment: Messages after the pageaddr line are the 
"ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000003150000001E has already been removed".

WAL directory yes the pg_xlog.

I think there was more going on with the network than they admitted at first which created the issue. We have passed our WAL archive limit for restarting so I will need to take another base backup to start things again. 

However...if something such as this happens in the future is there a way to move the WAL files to the replication server locally to have them replay/locate there or how would this situation be handled? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your are connecting to the master server you think you are connecting to, the one that has the file in its pg_xlog?  No amount of past network problems (assuming they are no longer occurring) should prevent the master from handing over the file if it still has it.

Comment: I should have clarified I suppose. The network issue I think had been and still was blocking at the time communication so I was dead in the water as it turns out (different from my original post). It thought it was communicating, but it was not...at least not completely. I could have however moved the WAL files manually if there was an option to have the replication server read WAL locally. Just to keep it going until the network issue was corrected.